# search functionality script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a search functionality in a table of contact but the script is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
  $("#myInput").on("keyup",function(){
    var value = $(this).val().toLocaleLowerCase();
    $("myTable tr").filter(function(){
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
}) ;
```

-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="contactsstyle.css">
<script src="contacts_script.js"></script>
<script src="search_script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onClick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="contact_department.html">Contact by Department</a>
  <a href="contact_administrator.html">Contact by Administrator</a>
</div>`

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size: 30px; cursor:pointer" onClick="openNav()">&#9776;open</span>
</div>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<br><br>

<tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>`
    <td><img src="img/(4x5)-female-placeholder.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /></td>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>`

    <td>Test</td>
    <td>jane.doe@test.com</td>`
    <td>000-000-0000</td>
  </tr>`

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML too for better clarity. Edit your question and add pls

Comment: The use of `filter` makes no sense here since you aare just using it as a for loop.

Comment: So do you have a `<myTable></myTable>` element?

Comment: I always saw `<table></table>`. first time i saw `<myTable></myTable>` (According to your code what is given in question)

Comment: And since the HTML  is now there, yep, issue is your selector is wrong for the table. (hopefully it is partial since it is invalid)

Comment: I added the html. myTable is an id in the tbody tag

Comment: what do you mean my selector is wrong for the table?

Answer (score -1):

You have missed the ampersand `#` for `$("myTable tr")`

The code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
      $("#myInput").on("keyup",function(){
        var value = $(this).val().toLocaleLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function(){
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    }) ;
```

Happy New Year!